# Multiple loop issue - pull 1 featured and continue the loop without it

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am writing a custom multiple loop to be used on a custom category template page. The loop should put one post that is checked as featured in admin, in a separate div, and continue the loop displaying all posts from the category except the featured.

Similar to the example provided on the [codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_in_Action) except I don't want to create a separate category for the featured post.

I am using [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/checkbox/) plugin for the check box that sets posts as featured.

I have the following issue with my code: `if ($post->ID == $do_not_duplicate) continue;` prevents rest of the loop to be executed. The code below just pulls the latest featured post.

Here is my function:

```
function featured() {
$featured = new WP_Query(array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'featured',
            'value' => '"top"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        ),
    'posts_per_page' => 1
    ));

while ( $featured->have_posts() ) : $featured -> the_post(); 
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
    <div id="featured">
        //featured post
    </div><!-- end #featured -->
<?php 
endwhile;
if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
if ($post->ID == $do_not_duplicate) continue;
    ?>
    <div class="container">
    // normal posts
    </div><!-- .charities-container -->
    <?php 
    endwhile;
endif;
}
```

Your fresh eyes will help a lot!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried echoing variables to see what are they holding? For instance, print `$do_not_duplicate` and see if it's holding the featured post's ID. What is exactly your problem? `if ($post->ID == $do_not_duplicate) continue;` doesn't work, so the featured post shows up twice?

Comment: Another thing that would be good to check is to echo have_posts(); at the top of the function. Depending where you call the function you may not have posts.

Comment: @mathielo hmmm you re right, variable isn't storing anything, and when i remove `if ($post->ID == $do_not_duplicate) continue;` from the begining of the second loop, the full loop is displayed, including the featured one, obviously... i am really stuck here, and i am using he code from codex, which makes me even more confused...

Comment: and just to make it clear, the problem is that the rest of the posts, below `if ($post->ID == $do_not_duplicate) continue;` are not being displayed

Comment: Just posted an answer as it wouldn't fit here in the comment box. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `$post` variable isn't being assigned with the current post information through the loop. As far as I can tell, you could try either one of these ways:

### 1) Global `$post`

The `$post` variable is within your `featured()` [function scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Therefore, when you run your loop, it is not being recognized as the `global $post` variable, which is the one WordPress fills with post information through the loop. Simply declare `$post` as a [`global`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) variable at the beginning of your function scope and you should be able to gather post information:

```
function featured() {
    global $post;
    // ... all your function code, $post->ID should work now
}
```

### or 2) Use `get_the_ID()`

You could replace `$post->ID` for WP's native function `get_the_ID()`. This is just about the same as the previous solution, as this function will retrieve the `ID` property from the global `$post` object automatically. I would take this as the best solution, as you don't have to worry about scope whenever using post functions (`get_the_ID()`, `get_the_title()`, etc) as long as the `$post` object is populated (after `the_post()` is called).

So you could replace this line:

```
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
```

for

```
$do_not_duplicate = get_the_ID();
```

and

```
if ($post->ID == $do_not_duplicate) continue;
```

for

```
if (get_the_ID() == $do_not_duplicate) continue;
```

---

Try either one of these solutions, I bet both should work for you. Actually, the example you took from codex page works just fine, the problem is that you applied it inside a local `function`. This way your `$post` variable is a local ([function scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)) variable, and not a [`global`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) one.

Comment: thank you for a very detailed and elaborate answer, if i could accept it twice i would :)